# Ajax Call inside JavaScripts using Yii Framework

Tags: javascript, yii

I am trying to use ajax function inside javascript, but its not calling its goes to failure part,

JS code :

```
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('my-event-listener',"
     $('#dedup_id').change(function(data){ 

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url:    '".$this->createUrl('CheckDedupField')."',
             data:  {crm_base_contact_id:1652},
             success: function(msg){
                 alert('Sucess')
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('failure');
            }
        });
    });
");
```

My controller code :

```
public function actionCheckDedupField($id)
{
    echo "Inside CheckDedup".var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Please anyone find out what mistake am doing here.

Comment: is your ajax triggered? or ajax function totally not working?

Comment: alert('failure'); only throwing its not firing to action

Answer (score 0):

You have to call ajax url as

```
 url:    '".$this->createUrl('checkDedupField')."', // change C to c
```

In URL, controller function names will start with lower case.

as per the comment. you are calling controller function with wrong name.

Then For missing parameter, change as

```
 data:  {id:1652},
```

Comment: what is the response you are getting in console? did you check the console?

Comment: Failuere message alone

Comment: This controller action not get firing

Comment: Did you check your access rules in your controller?

Comment: Console Error : REQUEST_URI=/yii/index.php/baseContact/basecontactCheckDedupField
HTTP_REFERER=http://www.example.com/yii/index.php/baseContact/edit/3925?asDialog=1
---
2014/02/03 12:12:41 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'The system is unable to find the requested action "basecontactCheckDedupField".' in D:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php:483

Comment: You are calling `basecontactCheckDedupField` in your ajax.  But function name is `CheckDedupField`. It ';s very clear 404 error. Then add your console error in question first.

Comment: Error while passing parameter

Comment: Now i changed that , i am facing problem in passing parameter ,

Comment: Update your question first.

Comment: 2014/02/03 12:27:02 [error] [exception.CHttpException.400] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Your request is invalid.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php:336
Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(309): CController->invalidActionParams(Object(CInlineAction))
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.